# What is the time complexity of the following code- find smallest missing number in an array

Tags: python, algorithm, set

the problem statement is:

given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Can anyone tell me what the time-complexity of the following solution to the code be:

```
def solution(A):
    m = max(A)
    if m < 1:
       return 1

    A = set(A)
    B = set(range(1, m + 1))
    D = B - A
    if len(D) == 0:
        return m + 1
    else:
        return min(D)
```

It has to be O(n) or greater because we are finding the max.
I had a doubt if creating a set from range 1 to the max element will be nlogn as the result will be a sorted set of elements..?

Comment: Why all the complexity? Isn't eh answer just `m+1`?

Comment: no, it's not, a number could be skipped like the first example

Comment: You might get a better answer if you ask a more focused question.  It seems like you're most interested in `set(range(1, m + 1))`, though I think `set(A)` and `B - A` are also very interesting for this question.

Comment: `set(B)` is not sorted, because `sets` are not sorted in python. Consider `solution([1,2,3])` and `solution([1,2,1_000_000])`: 1.21µs vs 107ms. Your algorithm's runtime depends mostly on the largest number in your array, because of `set(range(1, m+1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of this solution is linear: (`O(m + n)`) where `m` is the maximum element in `A` and `n` is the length of the input array `A`).

Here's a break down:

1. `max(A)` is `O(n)` since you have to look at each element of `A`.
2. `set(A)` is `O(n)` since you have to look at each lement of `A`.
3. `set(range(1, m + 1))` is `O(m)` since you iterate over every element between `1` and `m`.

The result is `O(m + n)`. While we can ignore any multiple of `n` or `m` (you don't say `O(2n)`), we can't ignore the minimum of `n` and `m`. The reason is that there is no guaranteed relation between `n` and `m`. They can be as different as `1` and `1e64`, or vice versa.

On a sidenote, this algorithm is really really bad. You can solve this problem in `O(n)` time and `O(n)` additional space.

A solution with `O(n)` time and space complexity could be as follows:

```py
def solve(A):
  seen = set()
  res = 1
  for el in A:
    seen.add(el):
    while res in seen:
      res += 1
  return res
```

It works as follows:

1. Init `res` to the best possible result (1)
2. keep track of seen elements with a set for constant time lookups.
3. iterate over `A`s elements
4. add them to the set.
5. increment `res` while it is present in `seen`

The reason this is of `O(n)` time complexity is that in the worst case the elements of the input array don't have any gap between them, start at one, and we have to increment `res` `n` times.

If there's any gap, we've found it already and sit there not incrementing further.

Comment: In the literal sense, *"O(m + n) where m is the maximum element in A"* is exponential, not linear.

Comment: Thank you so much. So what would a better algorithm be?

Comment: added a better algorithm @prison-mike